# Rails Radio Button returning Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, radio-button

I'm trying to pass a value from a radio button group in my view to a method in my controller. I've looked up many different ways of doing this and I get the same result, nil. 
So far I have:

In view

```
    <div id = "oilchange_buttons">
    <br><%= radio_button_tag 'oilchange', '0' %> Complete
    <%= radio_button_tag 'oilchange', '1' , true %> Pending
    </div>

<%= link_to 'Update', :remote => true, :action => "there" , :submit => 'oilchange_buttons' , > :id=> @huntingtonflatbedboxtruck %>
```

In controller

```
def there
if params[:oilchange] == '0'
Do stuff
end
```

At this point in the controller all I get is nil rather than a value. I'm stuck and have no clue what else to try. I'm still fairly new to rails, I'm probably missing something fundamental. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `form_tag`. If this is your first time to create any form in Rails, I'd suggest you read the link @Veger provided and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag.

You need `:remote` for `form_tag` the method, not for `link_to()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a form, otherwise your Update button, does not send the (form) information.

For more information on forms take a look at this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)